# How can I host a .jar file directly inside a war in Wildfly/JBoss?

Tags: java, jar, jboss, wildfly

So I have a very simple question.  I've got a fairly trivial .war file that will happily host any type of file I throw at it - except for a .jar file.

Here's my .war file:

WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" />
```

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.8.0_05-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
```

and the following four files:

```
index.html
folder/jar.jar
folder/jar.zip
folder/index.html
```

I'm deploying my war to a wildfly-8.1.0 server as "testwar.war". When I do so, I can access all of the files except folder/jar.jar via a perfectly normal URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/testwar/
http://localhost:8080/testwar/folder/
http://localhost:8080/testwar/folder/jar.zip
```

All of those work.  But

```
http://localhost:8080/testwar/folder/jar.jar
```

returns a 404.

I can't for the life of me figure out why the jar file won't show up, or how to fix it.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default servlet of Wildfly/Undertow has a list of allowed and disallowed extensions which can be configured in `web.xml` via init parameters. `jar` is disallowed by default.

Add the following to your `web.xml` to enable the `jar` extension:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>default-allowed</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>allowed-extensions</param-name>
         <param-value>jar</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>disallowed-extensions</param-name>
         <param-value>exe,bat,sh</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Out of curiosity - is this in any official documentation anywhere?

Comment: Don't think so, I was looking at the Undertow source code and then came across the forum post you found yourself. Undertow docs are rather sketchy, but the code is quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [JBoss community thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/241783?start=0&tstart=0)

Version 8.1.0 of WildFly by default refuses to serve out .jar files; you have to override that by adding the following block to your web.xml (by default, "jar" is a disallowed extension):

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>allowed-extensions</param-name>
          <param-value>jar, js, css, png, jpg, gif, html, htm, txt, pdf, jpeg, xml, zip</param-value>
      </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>disallowed-extensions</param-name>
          <param-value>class, war</param-value>
      </init-param>      
</servlet>
```